Get Device Name from Device Context Handle
I'm doing some work with MS Detours and one of the things I'm detouring is the Windows API GetDeviceCaps function which receives a handle to a device context as its first parameter.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the name of the device that this device context handle represents.  Basically I need to do the reverse of what the CreateDC function does, which takes a device name (amongst other things) and returns the device context handle.  Anyone know if that's possible?

AFAIK, there is no API for this task. And an HDC might not represent a device at all and thus not have a name

You could try to use GetDC to get the handle to the device context. Use GetDeviceCaps function to get the information for the device. And then you could try to use EnumDisplayDevices to get the name of the device.
